# Problem with QGIS Network Analyst (Basic)

Tags: network-analyst, shortest-path, qgis-3

I'm going through the QGIS training, [Lesson: Network Analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html), and I've encountered a problem with Network Analyst. When I open the Shortest Path (Pt to Pt) tool, I can set the Vector layer representing network and Path type to calculate, but when I click on the "`...`" to set the Start or End Points, nothing happens.

I've searched on this site and Googled around and haven't found anything. I've tried it in both 3.10 and 3.8 and the problem exists in both.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize that you needed to click in the text box, then click the corresponding points on the map itself. Thought you had to select points via the "`...`" button, the way you can select the "Vector layer representing network input" on this dialogue.